# How to add line breaks while adding text to div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

All, 
 I am working on populating  a div tag with text.

```
var centName;
 centName=centName+$(this).attr('data-centerName');//tried <br/> / '\n'

 $("#selOccs").text(centName.Trim(';'));
```

My div tag is like

```
  <div ID="selOccs" NAME="selOccs"  style="width: 350px; height: 100px;border:1px solid ;
                   overflow-y: scroll; scrollbar-arrow-color: blue; scrollbar-face-color: #e7e7e7; scrollbar-3dlight-color: #a0a0a0; scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #888888">

   </div>
```

The issue is adding line breaks. I need display the centName with line breaks.so far all the values are coming in one line[ as per the code].

I tried adding <--br/--> and '\n' but itseems to be not working..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var centName;

centName = centName + $(this).attr('data-centerName') + '<br/>';

$("#selOccs").html(centName.Trim(';'));
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of text and in the string you can then use `<br/>`